# After creating app using npx create-react-app <myproject> , and start app by using "npm start" i got this error mentioned below

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path E:\React js web\TextEdits/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\React js web\TextEdits\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\rehma\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-09-20T19_31_34_823Z-debug-0.log

Comment: Are you sure there is a `package.json` in the directory that you're calling `npm start` in? If you've just run create-react-app, the `package.json` file is in the generated `<myproject>` directory.

Comment: Thank you Henry...
I'm 100% sure i've package.json file in the directory <myproject>

Comment: What is the project name used while creating the app? and did you `cd` into the project folder?

Answer (score 2):

If there is a package.json file in your directory, it most likely has something to do with the spaces in your directory/path. This causes some issues with npm/npx sometimes, and it's usually best to avoid them. Windows is the only major OS that allows spaces in their directories, and commands are usually built on the assumptions that the path won't include spaces.  Since you're just starting a new project, I would recommend creating a whole new directory (such as E:/ReactProject/TextEdits) and trying to run the same commands there.

Answer (score 0):

1. sudo su
   2.npm outdate -g
   check your npm latest version!
   npm i command isn't work use npm i npm -g

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).